# ./script.zsh runs in compatability mode without shebang?

Tags: shell, zsh

A quick question of wondering.

I have a script that on line 37 does:

```
sub_commands+=("${sub_args[1]}")
```

It errors with

```
./script.zsh: 37: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

If run with dot-slash `./script.zsh`

`echo $SHELL` however gives expected zsh as shell because this is the shell it is executed from. But script behaves differently.

Is this sh/ksh compatibility mode kicking in?

Adding the correct shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
```

Solves this. Just curious what's going on? How it determines this? It even ends in .zsh

Comment: `$SHELL` is your login shell, not necessarily the shell that runs the script. Without a shebang, your OS defaults to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Is there a variable to check what shell it runs as?

Comment: Not really; presumably it either does not matter (the script confirms to the POSIX standard and could be run by *any* POSIX-compliant shell) or it uses shell-specific features and thus you know what shell is running if the script is running at all.

Comment: Thank you @chepner.